# Sidebar Object on Sublime Plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I want to build a plugin in order to affect the sidebar. Mainly visual stuff at first.
But I can't find any documentation about it.

Is it possible, as we can obtain view() and window() in the plugin, to have something like sidebar(), and be able to treat all the nodes on the Folders sections (for individual files) and interact with them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sidebar API in Sublime currently, so unfortunately what you are trying to do isn't possible at present.

Comment: @Martin yeah, it really is. It's one of the most-requested features from plugin developers, as there's so much that could be done with it. Maybe in ST4...